# How do I make data that the bpy.types.UIList can read?

Tags: python, interface

I started with the blender template ui_list_simple.py hoping i could create my own layer system. But i cant seem to create a data block that the layout.template_list can list. when i try to imput my own data the panel just does not render. any help is apreciated. My code is below. Here is a pic of what is showing. [image: How it looks]

```
import bpy


class MyLayer(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    root_dir: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='FILE_PATH')
    index: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    active_index: bpy.props.BoolProperty()

class COMPOSIT_OT_create_layer(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = '3e.creat_layer'
    bl_label = 'create_layer'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.types.Scene.My_Layers = []
        bpy.types.Scene.My_Layers.append(bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyLayer))
        return 'FINISHED'

class MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        ob = data
        slot = item
        ma = slot.material
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            if ma:
                layout.prop(ma, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
            else:
                layout.label(text="", translate=False, icon_value=icon)
        # 'GRID' layout type should be as compact as possible (typically a single icon!).
        elif self.layout_type == 'GRID':
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon_value=icon)



class UIListPanelExample(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "My Buttons"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "View"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        col.operator('3e.creat_layer')
        
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object


        layout.template_list("MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example", "", obj, "material_slots", obj, "active_material_index")


        layout.template_list("MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example", "compact", obj, "material_slots",
                             obj, "active_material_index", type='COMPACT')


classes = [
    UIListPanelExample,
    MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example,
    COMPOSIT_OT_create_layer,
    MyLayer
    ]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You need to use a CollectionProperty to create a list recognized by the serialization system, not a regular python list

Comment: @Gorgious is right. I found a good demo of it here if anyone else needs. https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i needed!